# Struts 2 hello world example index.jsp 404 error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I am done with googling but i didnot receive any help from there.
I am following the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_examples.htm
and trying to open simple index.jsp page.
while doing so i am receiving the error

> HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp
>
> ---
>
> type Status report
>
> message /HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp
>
> description The requested resource (/HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp) is
>   not available.
>
> ---
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.12

my web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

     <action name="" 
           >
            <result >/index.jsp</result>
      </action>
      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Tomcat stacktrace:

```
[![Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\IBM\Personal Communications\;C:\Program Files\IBM\Trace Facility\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Users\456278\Desktop\POI;C:\Eclipse IDE  for Java EE Developers 4.4;;.
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: \[SetPropertiesRule\]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloWorldStruts2' did not find a matching property.
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler \["http-bio-8080"\]
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler \["ajp-bio-8009"\]
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 477 ms
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using \[SHA1PRNG\] took \[151\] milliseconds.
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file \[struts-default.xml\]
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file \[struts-plugin.xml\]
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file \[struts.xml\]
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Overriding property struts.i18n.reload - old value: false new value: true
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Overriding property struts.configuration.xml.reload - old value: false new value: true
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler \["http-bio-8080"\]
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler \["ajp-bio-8009"\]
Sep 03, 2015 12:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1082 ms][1]][1]
```

image of my project explorer:

[image]

Comment: Post your project structure.

Comment: `<action name="" >
            <result >/index.jsp</result>
      </action>` your action name?

Comment: Why does your Struts action have no name?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi [Where The Struts Have No Name](https://youtu.be/GzZWSrr5wFI)

Comment: @Andrea Ligios hahahahaha! :-D

Comment: @Satya  i was doing some alteraton,it remained there...sorry for that but if i dont do that then also it leads to same error...

Comment: @Satya project directory has been added :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.jsp` page isn't at the root of your web content, it's in `WEB-INF`, so:

```
<result>/index.jsp</result>
```

points to a resource that doesn't exist.

```
<result>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</result>
```

More or less exactly as the error message states.